# showing repeating string using regex

Tags: regex, repeat

I have parsed a Remittance from a PDF email using a program called Email Parser.
I have the extracted text:

```
Service Dates Invoiced $ Paid $ Variance $ Reason
11065 155 01/05/19 58.20 46.15 12.05 RICW

10/05/19 58.20 46.15 12.05 RICW
28/05/19 58.20 46.15 12.05 RICW

11721 114 24/05/19 25.10 0.00 25.10 PREP

PREP Previously Paid
RICW Reduced to an amount within abcd guidelines
```

I am trying to split this into two sections which refers to The invoice number (eg. 11065 and 11721) then as many lines of items as below which is:
Price charged, price paid, variance.

I'm very new to regex and i can get the line:

```
11065 155 01/05/19 58.20 46.15 12.05 RICW
and
11721 114 24/05/19 25.10 0.00 25.10 PREP
```

however I guess i need to repeat the regex for the Date-\w{4} as many times until it his another \d{6}

My other issue is after the Invoice number there is a Pay number which needs to be ignored either way.

```
(\d{5}\s+?((\d){0,3})\s+)?(\d\d.\d\d.\d\d\s+\d+[.]\d\d\s+\d+[.]\d\d\s+\d+[.]\d\d\s+\w{4})
```

Is my attempt at the moment which gives the above lines.  I have tried a few different things but they are giving error results

I guess in theory what I wanted was

```
(\d{5}\s+?((\d){0,3})\s+)?(\d\d.\d\d.\d\d\s+\d+[.]\d\d\s+\d+[.]\d\d\s+\d+[.]\d\d\s+\w{4})*
```

Or something like that, eg. give me the invoice number if there, then give me all the date\$\$\$ strings after that number??

That is really all i have been able to do here. It is a pity the Invoice number isnt before every line!!

Comment: Are you writing that regex to use in some programming environment or in some application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you might do is match the string that starts with 5 digits (or use your more specific pattern to match exactly all the digits in the string)

Then use an optional part which will match a newline and repeats 1+ times matching a newline followed by matching lines that start with a date like pattern.

Note that it does not validate a date itself.

**Explanation**

```
^\d{5}\s+.*(?:\r?\n(?:\r?\n\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2}.*)+)?
```

- `^` Start of the string
- `\d{5}\s+`.*` Match 5 digits, 1+ whitespace chars and 0+ times any char except a newline
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\r?\n` Match a newline
  - `(?:` Non capturing group
    `\r?\n\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2}.*` Match a newline followed by a "date like" pattern
  - `)+` Close non capturing group and repeat it 1+ times
- `)?` close non capturing group and make it optional

See a [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PHoE1b/1)

Comment: Wow thats amazing. Thank you so much for going to the effort of explaining it all as well.